# Match possible exact pattern with grep

Tags: grep

I would like to grep for processes running on my machine that are either of the for `bin/myprocess` or `bin.rhel62/myprocess`. How could I also include this possible exact pattern?

I've tried `grep bin[.rhel62]/myprocess` but this doesn't seem to work. I've also tried `bin[\.rhel62]/myprocess` with no success either. Either I get no matches, or I'll match things like bin.rhheell62, which I don't want.

So, how can I match for a possible EXACT pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the OR `|` Operator and the `-E` flag. Just select for the actual expressions:

```
grep -E "bin/myprocess|bin.rhel62/myprocess"
```

Some more examples are [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is on other `grep`

```
grep -E "bin(.rhel62)?/myprocess" file
```

Or an `awk`

```
awk '/bin(.rhel62)?\/myprocess/'  file
```

By adding parentheses and a question mark it is optional `(.rhel62)?`